# Mocking only one variable inside function with gtest

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I'm coding in C and using gtest for C++ for unit testing.

I'd like to test situation where some variable gets integer overflow but incrementing that variable takes too long in UT. This variable is counter being written to directly only during initialization and is incremented on some events. My idea is to mock the counter to the maximum integer value during initialization, but I don't want to mock the function where counter is initialized because various other data important for UT is initialized in this function.

Is something like this possible with gtest or do I need to implement a stub which will have all the functionalities of real function and initialize wanted counter value to counter?

I cannot share the code since it's copyrighted, but here is excerpt showing general idea:

```
typedef struct {
    some_variable;
    another_variable;
    counter;
} data_structure_defined_only_in_this_file;

...

// check_some_parameters() isn't exported in header files
void check_some_parameters(data_structure_defined_only_in_this_file *container) {
    if (something == true)
        container->counter++;
}

...

// initialization() isn't exported in header files
void initialization() {
    data_structure_defined_only_in_this_file *container;
    ...
    container = (struct data_structure_defined... *)calloc(1, sizeof(struct data_structure_defined...));
}
```

I made another function during initialization after allocating memory to container. This function returned value which was assigned to counter as initial value.

source_file.c

```
// init_counter_val() IS exported to header file included in UT
int init_counter_val() { return 0; }

void initialization() {
    data_structure_defined_only_in_this_file *container;
    ...
    container = (struct data_structure_defined... *)calloc(1, sizeof(struct data_structure_defined...));
    container->counter = init_counter_val();
}
```

unit_test.cc

```
...
ON_CALL(mockObj, init_counter_val()).WillByDefault(Return(INT_MAX));
...
```

I mocked that function for unit test to return max integer value on function call but that solution wasn't accepted since production code would be changed to enable unit testing. But since neither data structure type nor functions where counter is written to aren't exported from source file, I believe mocking is impossible.

Comment: Split your initialization in sub functions and mock only the one you want ?

Comment: Care to share some code samples of what exactly are you trying to achieve?